# Пропадают пробелы в html при использовании file_get_html

Tags: php, html

В html имеется `<div class="cl">` и `<div class="cl ">`.

При выполнении следующего php кода:

```
    $html= file_get_html($link);
    ...
    foreach($tr->find('.cl') as $cl1)
    {
        echo '<br> cl1 = ' . $cl1->innertext . '<br>';
    }

    foreach($tr->find('.cl ') as $cl2)
    {
        echo '<br> cl2 = ' . $cl2->innertext . '<br>';
    }
    ...
```

пропадают пробелы и `"cl "` стает `"cl"`.

Пробовал передавать `$stripRN=false` в `file_get_html()` - не помогло.

Как сохранить все пробелы в html файле ?

Comment: `div[class*=cl\s]` попробуйте для поиска с пробелами

Comment: ответ удалил, поскольку вопрос был понят не так. Поступите банально - загрузите файл как обычный текст, замените `cl1 ` на `cl2` с помощью строковых функций, а потом скормите уже его на вход `str_get_html`